# On IPv6 all $HTTP GET and POST calls rejected in Ionic Android App shows Error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ipv6

On IPv6 all $HTTP GET and POST calls rejected in Ionic Android App   shows Error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". I already tried cordova whitelist plugin but still shows same Error .
Note : Working fine for IPv4 settings .

Config.xml  file:-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <widget id="com.jio.smart.vehicle" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
      <name>Name</name>
      <description>&#xD;&#xD;
            An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.&#xD;&#xD;
        </description>
      <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">&#xD;&#xD;
          Ionic Framework Team&#xD;&#xD;
        </author>
      <content src="index.html"/>
      <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
      <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
      <access origin="cdvfile://*"/>
      <allow-navigation href="*" />
      <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
      <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
      <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
      <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
      <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"/>
      <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
      <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
      <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan"/>
      <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
      <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
      <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
      <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20"/>
      <hook type="before_run" src="hooks/appBeforeBuild.js" />
      <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
      </feature>
      <platform name="android">
        <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
      </platform>
      <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    </widget>
```

Comment: Does your IPv6 connectivity actually work properly?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes After changing APNS settings of my device from IPv4 to IPv6 other apps like youtube works properly but my app didnt initiate the $HTTP call